# Build same certificate with android system

Tags: android

I am trying to use android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL permission. I read in the documentation that: add android:protectionLevel="signature".
But it doesn't work.

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a 3rd party app with that permission.
The meaning of

> android:protectionLevel="signature"

Is that only apps that were signed with the system's certificates when the Android image was made can have this permissions.

You have to either not use this permission or, if relevant, create your own ROM from the AOSP and place your app there.

Comment: oh thanks, i see an this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.telenav.launcher&hl=vi&gl=US  can do it. It use to listen player of system. Is is  signed with the system's certificates?

Comment: I highly doubt it's signed with the system's signature as it will be built in by default in the system. (not a must, but no reason not to).
They probably found a work around for the specific functionality you are looking for or, only supporting rooted devices.